# CQ5 Query Debugger

Tags: aem

I am trying to pull all the pages in AEM 6.1 whose cq:last modified date is greater than cq:last replicated.to put it in a basic English i want all the pages which are having both the green(activated) and the blue(modified) colors highlighted in siteadmin

Can anyone please help me with this query

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues are you facing?

Comment: I have used the below query and it is yielding the correct results in AEM 6.1 but it is not giving me the correct result in AEM 5.6.

# show pages that have been modified since they were last published
path=/content/geometrixx
property=cq:lastModifiedBy
property.value=reference-adjustment-service
dateComparison.property1=cq:lastModified
dateComparison.property2=cq:lastReplicated
dateComparison.operation=greater

Comment: Your comment contradicts your question. Can you update your question with the details provided so that you get better answers? Also, in general 5.6 and 6.1 can have query result differences depending on index setup. You might want to mention these details also.